# How do you call a class that is inheriting another class?

Tags: object-oriented

If class is declared like this

```
class Foo : IFoo
```

From IFoo point of view, Foo is called **implementation**.

If class is declared like this

```
class Foo : Bar
```

Then Foo **derives** from Bar.

How do you call a **Foo** from **Bar** class point of view?

- Inheritor?
- Derivative?

Comment: The terms you'll usually hear are 'subclass' or 'derived class'

Comment: I was looking for a single word. I completely ignored the 'subclass' :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Foo` is a [subclass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)#Subclasses_and_superclasses) of `Bar`, `Bar` is the parent class (or superclass) of `Foo`

Comment: The preferred terminology is language dependent. C++ uses **derived** class, for example (which, IMO, is a far better choice).

Comment: Also, if you're using "subclass" then "superclass" is usually the inverse rather than "parent".